# Animation performance jQuery, css transition ? How can i have a better performance here?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to implement a sort of a magic line that follow your mouse when you're on the header navigation menu.

For example :

http://www.infinitesquare.com/#actualites

Here it works perfectly, very smooth.

I typed a jQuery script myself, it works but it's not smooth as i want to.

Here is my HTML :

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="active"><p>Accueil</p></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class=""><p>A propos</p></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class=""><p>Contact</p></a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class=""><p>Nos technos</p></a>
        </li>
        <li id="magic-line"></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Here is the specific CSS:

```
#magic-line{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: #7190C9;
    left: 0px;
    top:97px;
}
```

Here is my script :

```
var barre = $("#magic-line");
$("a").hover(function(){
    var thisA = $(this);
    switch(thisA.children("p").html()) {
    case "Accueil":
        var aWidth = thisA.parent("li").width();
        var offset = thisA.offset().left;
        barre.css({left : offset, width : aWidth, transition : "0.5s"});
        break;
    case "A propos":
        var offset = thisA.offset().left;
        var aWidth = thisA.parent("li").width();
        barre.css({left : offset, width : aWidth, transition : "0.5s"});
        break;
    case "Contact":
        var offset = thisA.offset().left;
        var aWidth = thisA.parent("li").width();
        barre.css({left : offset, width : aWidth, transition : "0.5s"});
    break;
    case "Nos technos":
        var offset = thisA.offset().left;
        var aWidth = thisA.parent("li").width();
        barre.css({left : offset, width : aWidth, transition : "0.5s"});
    break;
}
});
```

Do you have any idea how can i optimize this script ?

Here is a JsFiddle of my script :

https://jsfiddle.net/3jeu2L7v/

But it's smoother than on my website, how can i explain so ?

Comment: Could you provide a jsFiddle?

Comment: Seems perfectly smooth to me, then you must have some other problems on your website. If we cannot reproduce it, you won't get an answer, so maybe show your website..

Comment: Agree with @ssc-hrep3, it looks smooth to me too, maybe there's a something else in your website that's making this part look "flickery".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to improve animation performance is by using CSS transforms. So, instead of changing `left` and `width` we'd be using `transform: translateX() scaleX()`.

The drawback is that CSS transforms are not supported by older browsers and you might have to deal with CSS prefixes in some cases (i.e. -webkit-transfor, -moz, etc), but CSS transforms will trigger hardware acceleration.

I suggest you try an animation library like [GSAP](http://greensock.com/) that will take care of all this for you. It will use CSS transforms when available and add the required CSS prefixes if needed. Of course, this will add an extra dependency to your project and a few kilobytes ;)

```js
var items = $('li');
var bar = $('.bar');

items.on('mouseover', function(){
  var item = $(this);
  var w = item.width();
  var x = item.position().left + 15; // 15 is the margin form the CSS, change this accordingly

  bar.css({
    transform: 'translateX(' + (x + w / 2 - 1) + 'px) scaleX(' + w + ')',
    //left: x,
    //width: w
  });
})
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 20px 50px;
}

nav{
  padding: 15px 15px 20px 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  position: relative;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline;
  margin: 15px;
}

nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #888;
}

nav .bar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 3px;
  left: 0;
  background: #0ae;
  bottom: 16px;
  transition: 0.5s all;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="bar"></div>
</nav>
```

Here's a working example: http://codepen.io/victmo/pen/KMMNVG

If you get a change, check out this video / article about animation performance using CSS transforms. It's kind of old but still valid: http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Probably, the reason this animation runs slowly lies somewhere else in your codebase. But there's one thing I'd optimise in this code.
Namely, there's no need to disturb the DOM to calculate width and offset of the "Barre" each time user hovers. Much better to do it once (and update if layout changes) and use those precalculated values.

For example like this:

```
var barre = $("#barre-du-futur"),
// cache more selectors for later use
    menuLink = $("a");

// This one will contain precalculated widths and offsets    
var barreProps;

$(document).ready(function(){
    barre.css({left : $(".active").offset().left, width : $(".active").parent("li").width(), transition : "0.5s"});
  // Capture Barre properties
  captureBarreProps();
});

$(window).resize(function(){
    barre.css({left : $(".active").offset().left, width : $(".active").parent("li").width(), transition : "0.5s"});
  // RECapture Barre properties
  captureBarreProps();
});

// Optimization
function captureBarreProps() {
    // Reset the object
    barreProps = {};

  // Loop through the links to precalculate properties
  menuLink.each(function() {

        var curMenuLink = $(this);
    var curItemName = curMenuLink.children("p").html();
    if ( curItemName.toString() !== "" ) {
      barreProps[curItemName] = {
        width: curMenuLink.parent("li").width(),
        offset: curMenuLink.offset().left
      };    
    } else {
        // error: Something wrong with one of the Menu Items
    }

  });
}

// Now, there's no need in switch and hardcoding names
menuLink.hover(function(){
    var thisA = $(this),
      curItemName = thisA.children("p").html(),
      curBarreProps = barreProps[curItemName];

    barre.css({left : curBarreProps.offset, width : curBarreProps.width, transition : "0.5s"});
});
```

here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Patat/xyq5khna/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger the hover on the li which is divided trough four (in your case) so that them fill the whole line from left to right without space between them, but getting the size of the a-Tag.

Impotrant is this line in your css

```
nav ul li {
   width: 25%
}
```

And this is a quite shorter way to write your function:

```
$("li").each(function() {
  $(this).hover(function (){
    var trigger = $(this).find('a'),
        left        = trigger.offset().left,
        width       = trigger.outerWidth();
    barre.css({'left': left, 'width': width})
  })
})
```

I rewrote your fiddle:
[Your rewritten fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cg9bhm18/)